# google sheet conditional formatting with NETWORKDAYS.INTL

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using the following formula in google sheet for conditional formatting, its for date

=OR($C2="", $I2>=($D2+8))

now unable to understand how to add "NETWORKDAYS.INTL" in D2+8, so that it will now count Sunday

Comment: Post few sample data. You may share a sample google-sheet here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.